# Strange behaviour binding event to element jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok weird one this, I'm binding a `change` event to a select. The below is the exact code, I've taken out all the logic to diagnose the issue.

```
$('#js-course-applications').on('change', function(){
    alert("Wey!");    //doesn't fire
});

console.dir($('#js-course-applications')); // correctly shows control in console

$("body").on("change", "#js-course-applications", function () {
    alert("Another Wey!"); // fires correctly
});
```

My question is why is the first event not registering? The DOM is loaded before binding. I've never encountered anything like it, and to add to the confusion the first method of `.on()` was working as intended earlier in development.

Edit: Using jQuery version 2.1.3 for what it's worth

```
<select name="CourseApplications" class="js-course-applications" id="js-course-applications" data-courses="[{&quot;GUID&quot;:&quot;db0ce555-a775-e611-943e-005056ab59d4&quot;,&quot;FirmOffer&quot;:false,&quot;ApplicationCourse&quot;:&quot;Mechanical Engineering, BEng (Hons) (Foundation)&quot;,&quot;ApplicationStatus&quot;:&quot;Conditional Insurance&quot;,&quot;CourseType&quot;:&quot;UG&quot;},{&quot;GUID&quot;:&quot;7fbd6337-766b-e511-9432-005056ab59d4&quot;,&quot;FirmOffer&quot;:false,&quot;ApplicationCourse&quot;:&quot;Electrical and Electronic Engineering, BEng (Hons)&quot;,&quot;ApplicationStatus&quot;:&quot;Conditional Firm&quot;,&quot;CourseType&quot;:&quot;UG&quot;}]">
    <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="db0ce555-a775-e611-943e-005056ab59d4">Mechanical Engineering, BEng (Hons) (Foundation)</option>
    <option value="7fbd6337-766b-e511-9432-005056ab59d4">Electrical and Electronic Engineering, BEng (Hons)</option>
    <option value="-1">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please create a pen for better understanding.

Comment: @pixellab It works in a snippet - as it should. My question is what would cause it to not work?

Comment: What would cause it not to work is if the element is not yet available (the DOM not being ready) when you try to add the listener.

Comment: @connexo You're right ordinarily, but the method that contains the code is called in a dom ready event. None of the controls are dynamic either. Even more strange, if pause in the debugger, check the element exists then run it still won't bind the first method

Comment: Then please add minimal HTML to demonstrate the issue. Also please try the same using native JS DOM API to make sure it's not a jQuery bug.

Comment: @connexo The code works as intended if I create a simple snippet. I've attached my markup where it's occuring

Comment: Show the **rendered** HTML only.

Comment: @connexo I've copied html from dev tools

Comment: Are you sure there's only one element with that id? Otherwise selecting it using the id will always only find the first occurrence. You need to make sure each id value in your whole document is unique.

Comment: @connexo Yep, I added the id when trying to figure out what's going on. I was originally using `.find()` from the form and the class selector

Comment: So you're not cloning this from a `template` element where the same `id` is in use? Are you sure? Check the rendered HTML for the id. You might not even be aware of that `template ` element which I assume the framework you're using is addding.

Comment: @connexo Not at all, just a regular old static html element. It's not urgent if I don't figure it out as I've used the `on('body')` to resolve. I was just curious if anyone else has come across the problem

Comment: It won't have anything to do with the problem, just a sidenote: `selected="" disabled=""` is actually invalid HTML as the empty string is not allowed as a value on Boolean attributes. Either omit the `=""` outright (which some server-side template engines like Thymeleaf cannot), or repeat the property name `selected="selected" disabled="disabled"`

Comment: @connexo yeah good point, that's not in my markup - I just have `selected`, `disabled` but gets rendered in chrome with quotes. I'll amend though to include values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would cause it not to work is if the element is not yet available (the DOM not being ready) when you try to add the listener. jQuery offers a convenient method to make sure the DOM is fully parsed and all elements are accessible called `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#js-course-applications').on('change', function(){
    alert("Wey!");    //doesn't fire
  });
})
```

The event delegation thing works because here the element only needs to be accessible when the event occurs. It is typically used to add listeners for events triggered by elements that get added to the page dynamically by Javascript.

Please note that event delegation only works on events that bubble. (For example `blur` and `focus` do not bubble by default.)

Are you sure there's only one element with that `id`? Otherwise selecting it using the `id` **will always only find the first occurrence**. You need to make sure each `id` value in your whole document is **unique**.

Comment: I'm a buffoon... I'm using Sitecore and some additional code was rendering a duplicate placeholder. It was hard to spot as the place holder was hidden - hence duplicate id as you suggested in the comments.Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Adding that to my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Because the element `#js-course-applications` may be a dynamically generated element. That was really not existing when the event was bound. Or if the element was not dynamically generated then possibly event was not attached after DOM ready state.

> The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that *already exist* when the code executes. It won't get bound to elements created in the future.

So, you will need to use [Event Delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) here. As you are doing in your second method.